# Possible to see any user's site preferences (privacy breach)

Tags: bug, status-completed, privacy, security, preferences

Most current user profile-related pages contain user-id in the URL section, e.g. my edit profile page:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/339911

If you try to open it you will see a 404 stub:

> [image: 404]

But it's not true for [Preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/339911) and [Flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/339911/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%84/flair) pages. For these pages, it seems at first sight that you can access another user's data, but I hope there are no security issues, just UI elements not linked to any data (you need to be logged in to see these pages). For instance here are [Sonic's "preferences"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/377214):

> [image: Sonic the K-Day Hedgehog]

and [Glorfindel's Flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/anyname/flair):

> [image: Glorfindel]

Anyway, I suggest hiding such weird pages and displaying the same 404 page as for other profile-related tabs.

Bonus panel: for SO sites where theme support is enabled, changing the theme for not-yours page leads to displaying an empty popup from the top of the page:

> [image: Not yours theme]

Comment: Flair is public and can be accessed anyway, always was. Preferences however is a different case, and clear breach of privacy.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard It's weird if you want to emplace another user Flair to your site (ofcourse if you don't write an article about top SE users).

Comment: I've contacted SE as per the instructions for reporting serious security issues with a link to this issue report.

Comment: Yeah...doesn't that mean you can download their activity data as well?  If so, then quick fix please!

Comment: We're looking into it right now

Comment: @Ollie The download route always looks at the currently logged in user's info, so no downloads would've been exposed this way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thanks for reporting! This has been fixed in `rev 2020.11.4.37941`.